# How can I embed a Google Docs Collection into a webpage?

Tags: php, google-docs

I have a Google Docs "Collection" within my organization, which uses Google Apps. I want to make all of the files in this collection publicly accessible for download via a webpage. I know I can "share it with a link" and put an iframe in the web page, but is there a utility, plugin, or class (maybe PHP?) that I could use which would read all the documents in a collection and allow downloading them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

Documents lots of things you can do.

v3.0 is in testing and very feature packed, but I believe they dropped PHP support from it. So you will have to use v1.0 for PHP.